# Can Windows 2016 EC2 instance provisioned by ElasticBeanstalk be connected to SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk, aws-systems-manager

Can Windows 2016 EC2 instance provisioned by ElasticBeanstalk be connected to SSM in AWS?
I'm specifically asking this as I don't see the EB default role containing any SSM policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not. EB-provisioned instance is in the end a standard EC2 with EB agent running.

I'm sure you can install SSM agent and add your own policies to the EB-provided IAM Role that allows SSM access. That should work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try out editing the IAM role for the whole EB and installing SSM agents.